# How to customise an Odoo Warning?

Tags: python, odoo

I have created a warning like this:

```python
mensajeAdvertencia["deposit_amount"] = "Pago Inicial"
mensajeAdvertencia["plan_reference"] = "Referencia Pago Inicial"

raise Warning(
    _("Por favor ingresar los siguientes campos: %s" 
      % sorted(mensajeAdvertencia.values()))
)
```

[image: original_warning]

But I would like to show the message like this, in a more readable way:

[image: needed_warning]

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Trying to be more concise and descriptive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will need to add a `\n` whenever you want to add a new line:

```python
sorted_values = sorted(mensajeAdvertencia.values())
raise Warning(
    _("Por favor ingresar los siguientes campos: \n\n%s" 
      % '\n'.join(sorted_values))
)
```

**Note**: I recommend that you write your messages and code in English. You should use the translation system to translate it to Spanish.